# How to know when a an async function has finished when inside an object?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I have a class that contains an object, in order to use the properties of the object, NSURLSession must complete its async data request. How do I go about creating a callback through an object to know when that function is done and I can call on those properties.

Answer (score 0):

You do not gave the example of the code, so I'll write in the abstract. You need to put a call the method that works with your object inside the completion of `NSURLSession` object. For example it may looks like this:

```
// This is your object
struct SomeData {
        var someValue: Int = 0
    }

// This is class that use it
class Foo {
    var someData: SomeData

    init() {
        someData = SomeData()
        requestData()
    }

    // This is your function that need to wait for the request
    func doActionWithData() {
        print(someData.someValue)
    }

    // This is request
    func requestData() {
        // Make request with your params
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(...)
        ...
        // For example you do it like this
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // here you have data for your object you can get it from 
            // response and then call function to work with it
            self.someData.someValue = ...
            self.doActionWithData()
        })
    }
}
```